# run visual studio code in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just use 'code' in ubuntu.

1. i download code_1.74.2-1671533413_amd64.deb in site
2. sudo apt install ./code_1.74.2-1671533413_amd64.deb
3. then update package

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install code # or code-insiders
```

then i have problem like this.

> /mnt/c/Users/jhyun/Desktop$ code
> To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.
> Do you want to continue anyway? [y/N]

how can i solve this?

Comment: WSL is different from normal Linux VM/containers, so you'd better follow those sentences and choose No. The WSL specific guide is at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Answer (score 0):

You have two options when running VSCode under WSL:

- Run the Linux version, as you are doing currently.

  The Linux version should run fine, but is limited to compiling, running, and debugging Linux applications.  It will not be able to use the Windows versions of any of your development tools.  This may or may not be a problem for you.  If you only plan to use Linux toolchains from WSL, then the Linux version of VSCode will handle those just fine.
- Run the Windows version and install the [WSL Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) or the [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) (which includes the WSL Extension).

  This has the advantage of being able to use Linux tools (through a "shim server" that is automatically installed in WSL when you launch `code`) or native Windows tools.

  As a native Windows application, it should also be a bit better integrated with the Windows desktop.

There are just very few reasons (and I can't think of any of them at the moment) why you would want to use the Linux version in this case.